# Find start and end quotes within a string

Tags: php

I have a string of text as follows:

```
The nice man said "How's things today" and I replied "All is good thanks".
```

I would like to replace the double quotes for fontawesome icons. If I do a string replace on double qoutes it works fine. But as expected this just gives me a generic lefthand quote mark for every double quote within the string.

My current code:

```
$str = The nice man said "How's things today" and I replied "All is good thanks".

$str = str_replace('"', '<i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

Outputs:

```
The nice man said <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>How's things today<i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> and I replied <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>All is good thanks<i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>.
```

Desired Output:

```
The nice man said <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>How's things today<i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> and I replied <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>All is good thanks<i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>.
```

---

Example Output: http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1975/

Comment: OP doesn't deal with HTML in the first place. @Jens

Comment: Your output and expected out are looking same?

Comment: @SahilGulati - They don't. The first has `fa-quote-left` for all quotation marks while the the last one has `fa-quote-right` for all the right quotation marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure double quotes are there as the same as what we are seeing in the subject string (balanced, no escaped double quote inside) then a regex will do the job:

```
echo preg_replace('~(")([^"]+)(")~', '<i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>\\2<i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>', $str);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/7hlYe)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain what the pattern is doing exactly please?

Comment: The regex tries to find and capture three parts from input string: 1- a double quote (opening) 2- everything except a double quote 3- a double quote again (closing). Then by `preg_replace()` function's replacement argument, it replaces first and third capturing groups and leaves middle part intact.